# create Index Linked List from a plain List

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I'm currently playing with an indexed linked list. The basic data type is given by

```hs
data LList (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) where
  Nil  ::LList 0 a
  (:@) ::a -> LList n a -> LList (n + 1) a
```

**I was wondering whether it's possible to define a mapping from `[]` to `LList`?**

The return type depends on runtime information as the length of the list is, of course, not available at compile time.

```
fromList :: ? => [a] => LList ? a
fromList = undefined
```

The full source code of the playground [is available here](https://github.com/keksnicoh/thinking-with-types-notes/blob/master/src/LList.hs).

Comment: Chances are you're going to end up wanting real inductive natural numbers (`data Nat = Z | S Nat`) rather than GHC `Nat`. The latter requires a plugin to do any non-trivial reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use an existential. This wraps the length of the list and the list itself into a pair, which does not show its length in the type.

```
data SomeLList a = forall n. SomeLList (LList n a)
```

This says that a `SomeLList a` consists of a term of the form `SomeLList @(n :: Nat) (_ :: LList n a)`. This type is in fact equivalent to `[]` (except for an extra bottom and no infinities)

```
fromList :: [a] -> SomeLList a
fromList [] = Nil
fromList (x : xs) | SomeList xs' <- fromList xs = SomeList (x :@ xs)
```

You get the type out of the pair by matching:

```
something :: [a] -> ()
something xs
  | SomeList xs' <- fromList xs
  = -- here, xs' :: SomeList n xs, where n :: Nat is a new type (invisibly) extracted from the match
    -- currently, we don't know anything about n except its type, but we could e.g. match on xs', which is a GADT and could tell us about n
    ()
```